# Plotting with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm receiving an error when running the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = 5E5
q = .03
p = .38
e = math.e

x = np.array (range(5))
#factor = e ** ( - x ( p + q ) )
#top = (1 - e ** ( - x ( p + q ) ))
#bottom = (1 + (q / p) ( e ** ( - x ( p + q ) ) ))
y = m * ( (1 - e ** ( - x * ( p + q ) )) / ((1 + (q / p) ( e ** ( - x * ( p + q ) ) ))) )

plt.plot(x,y,label='y = x**2')

plt.title("Testing")
plt.xlabel("x axis")
plt.ylabel("y axis")
plt.grid(alpha = .4,linestyle='--')
plt.plot(x,y,label='y=x**2')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

I don't understand the error TypeError: 'float' object is not callable shows up when I run the code. I tried modifying the expression, etc., but to no avail. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(q / p) ( e ** ( - x * ( p + q ) ) )
```

You are missing an operator between `(q / p)` & `( e ** ( - x * ( p + q ) ) )`

Try:

```
y = m * ( (1 - e ** ( - x * ( p + q ) )) / ((1 + (q / p) * ( e ** ( - x * ( p + q ) ) ))) )
```

Comment: Please don't leave full answers to typos. Vote to close instead.